# Как сделать так, чтобы содержимое секции было полностью заполнено?

Tags: html, css

Я использую Swiper JS для пролистывания полностраничных блоков, но не могу сделать так чтобы содержимое занимало все пространство внутри секции, а именно растянулось сверху и снизу в полный рост. У меня стоит правило

```css
section {
   padding: 60px 0 !important;
  
}
```

И поэтому содержимое секции не растягивается полностью, но как сделать так, чтобы содержимое секции растянулось и были заполнены эти зеленые пустоты? Я специально сделал фон секции зеленым, чтобы было видно лучше

Сам сайт cn76553.tmweb.ru

Весь код jsfiddle.net/u2cj3gw7/

**PS данная секция называется .services и чтобы пролистывать полностраничные блоки надо выбрать Интернет магазин > Узнать подробнее> Примеры работ**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Зачем нужны стили?

```
section {
   padding: 60px 0 !important;
}
```

Если для того чтобы контент не попадал под меню то их лучше применять, как я поимаю, к элементу с классом `.wrapper`

Для класса `.services-first-slider` добавьте стиль

```
background-size: cover;
```

тогда картинка растянется на весь блок

[image: background-size: contain]
[image: background-size: cover]

Comment: не сработало, увы

Comment: вы уверены что стиль применился? что показывает инспектор?

Comment: я добился нужного путем установки .services .wrapper {padding: 60px !important;} но почему-то это правило не работает для третьего слайда services-third-slider

Comment: данный способ вероятнее всего решает проблему только на вашем устройстве, с другим разрешением может понадобиться другое значение не 60px, свойство background-size: cover; специально создано для того чтобы картинка заполняла все пространство почему оно у вас не работает как вы его применяете?

Comment: вот так .services-first-slider {
    background: url(../img/services-bg.jpg) center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: right;
    position: relative;
}

Comment: инспектор показывает, что стиль применился, но изменений нет